# How to inject and change database / data source on runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Firstly I have created standard repository using `JpaRepository` for my entity `Foo` class to store it in database.

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
}
```

Furthermore as my second data access object I would like to use my own implementation of this simply CRUD operation interaface, which would store data in file.

```
public interface FooDao {
    Collection<Foo> getAll();
    Foo getById(Long id);
    void removeById(Long id);
    void update(Foo foo);
    void insert(Foo foo);
}
```

And separately it works fine when I have both variable manually declared like this

```
@Autowired
private FooRepository fooRepository;

@Autowired
private FooDao fooDao;
```

From services I use some kind of `switch` statement to identify which data source currently user chose, using helper variable:

```
private String datasource = "db";    // or "file"
```

But this solution require using `if` statement to determine which data access object I need to use, what duplicate code and of course is not elegant.

```
public Foo getOne(Long id){
    Foo result = null;

    if(datasource.equals("db"))
        result = fooRepository.findOne(id); 
    else if(datasource().equals("file"))
        result = fooDao.getById(id);            

    return result;
}
```

How can I change dynamically on runtime between those different and not compatible interfaces? How can I make them compatible to use them interchangeable, how properly write some kind of wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

you could make your `FooDao` implementation implement the `FooRepository` interface rather than your own one. In this way you would just provide 2 different implementations for the interface and can handle them the same way in your service. They would just be two different Spring beans:

```
   @Autowired
   private FooRepository fooRepository;

   @Autowired
   private FooRepository fooDao;
```

And your implementation would look like:

```
@Component
public class FooDaoImpl implements FooRepository {
  // your own implementations for the methods declared by FooRepository 
}
```

In your using class you could just use an access method to get one of this interfaces like this one:

```
private FooRepository getFooDataAccess() {
  return "db".equals(datasource) ? fooRepository : fooDao;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for sure that's a cleaner solution. But is there a way to configure spring to inject those beans automatically without this helper variable or is this good enough solution?

Comment: That depends much on the context and requirement. At which time is `datasource` determined? (Runtime, Compiletime, Startuptime, ...)

Comment: at runtime, user can at any time switch between those two data sources

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the conditional statements, you `need` to use a common interface.
The problem is that neither `FooDao` nor `JpaRepository` are good candidates to be the common interface.

`JpaRepository` subclasses benefits at runtime of a generated implementation, so you could not back the generated implementation to the `FooDao` interface.

Make the `FooDao` subclass implement `JpaRepository` makes no sense either as it forces your `FooDao` implementation to be coupled to  `JpaRepository` and to implement all methods (several dozen) of that while it probably could not.
You could throw `UnsupportedOperationException` for the unsupported methods but it will make your code more brittle as misuses will be detected only at runtime.

So I think that in these specific conditions your actual way wrapping the two objects is a valid approach.

Comment: But how to properly wrap those two interfaces? Or is there a way to inject it somehow?